# Url redirection, how to redirect the following with mod_url rewrite

Tags: url, redirect

I want to redirect all incoming requests to:

domain.com/**search?check**=listings&action=pjActionSearch etc etc 
to

domain.com/**index.php?page=search&check**=listings&action=pjActionSearch etc etc

So basicly any url beginning "search?check" with ending with anything

to the lower url starting with "index.php?page=search&check" ending with anything.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it, and it turned out my other rules caused the problem it rewrote my rule for this change...

So the solution:

i only need to change **search?** to **index.php?page=search&** SO:

RewriteRule ^search? index.php?page=search& [L,QSA]

QSA flag indicates that the original query string should be appended to the new URL.